# Creating linestring geometry from jsonb column

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to create a line from an array of x,y coordinates inside of a jsonb field. Here is the format of the field:

[image]

I created a linestring geometry column, but having difficulty with the syntax. Do I need to make points from the x,y first?  The j.line part is where I think i need to make points?

```
UPDATE waze.wazejams SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(**j.line**),4326)
```

I'm very green with PostGIS so go easy :)

UPDATE: I'm thinking I need to create a multipoint geometry to house the multiple vertexes along the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*jsonb* support is great, but handling them as rows is a little tricky. The key is to get familiar with the [operators and functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to properly access *json/jsonb* objects.
To update `<your_table>`'s `geom` column with row-based LINESTRINGs from your *jsonb* data, run

```
WITH
 lines AS (
    SELECT <id>,
           ST_MakeLine(
             ST_MakePoint(
               (line -> n ->> 'x')::NUMERIC,
               (line -> n ->> 'y')::NUMERIC
             )
           ) AS geom
    FROM <your_table>
    CROSS JOIN generate_series(0, jsonb_array_length(line)) AS n
    GROUP BY <id>
  )

UPDATE <your_table> AS a
SET geom = ST_SetSRID(b.geom, <your_srid>)
FROM lines AS b
WHERE a.<id> = b.<id>
```

What's happening:

- in the *CTE* (i.e. `WITH ...`), for the each row in `<your_table>`

  - generate a series of numbers as index `n`, according to the length of the
    *jsonb* array
    (`... CROSS JOIN generate_series(...) ...`)
  - access the objects based on that index in numeric order (`->`) and extract the value of key '*x*' and '*y*' (`->>`) into `ST_MakePoint()`
  - pass those points to `ST_MakeLine()` in consequtive order (that is done implicitly here), grouped by the tables `<id>` column

  and create a temporary table `lines` with the geometries and the tables `<id>` column
- in the `UPDATE`, for each row in `<your_table>`

  - select that geometry from `lines` with matching `<id>`
  - set *SRID* to `<your_srid>` and copy into column `geom`

All parameters in `<>` are to be replaced with the names of your table/columns/SRID, of course.

Hope that made sense to you?

Comment: Awesome!  That worked.  Thank you for the explanation.